# Verilog Random Number Generator

Tags: verilog

I'm new to Verilog and I'm trying to create a 4-bit binary Random Number Generator. The program is as follows, could anyone help me by mentioning the errors?

I initially tried out this:

```
module rng (d);
 inout[3:0]d;
 //wire[3:0]d;
 //input clk, rst;
 //wire [3:0] w;

 dff f1(a[0],clk,d[0],rst);
 dff f2(a[1],clk,d[1],rst);
 dff f3(a[2],clk,d[2],rst);
 dff f4(a[3],clk,d[3],rst);

 xorper p(d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3],a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);//permutations
 //dff f1(a,clk,q,rst);
 dff x(d,clk,q,rst);
endmodule
```

I also tried out this:

```
module re(b,q,clk,rst);
 input [3:0]q;
 input clk,rst;
 wire [3:0]q,a;

 output [3:0]b;
 reg [3:0]b;


 rox f1(q[0],q[1],q[2],q[3],a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);//permutations
 rod f2(a,clk,b,rst);//dff
 always@(posedge clk) begin
 if (rst==1'b0) begin
  b[0]=q[0];
  b[1]=q[1];
  b[2]=q[2];
  b[3]=q[3];
 end else if(rst==1'b1)
  b[0]=1'bx;
  b[1]=1'bx;
  b[2]=1'bx;
  b[3]=1'bx;
 end

endmodule
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Your original question was written quite poorly, I've cleaned it up some for you (please use a similar format in any future questions). As to your original question, you need to be a lot more descriptive about what actual problem you are having. Did you try to simulate this? How do you know it's not working? What errors did you get?

Comment: [link](http://cas.ee.ic.ac.uk/people/dt10/research/thomas-10-lut_sr_rngs.pdf)<br/> the block diagram is on page 3 fig1.(A)

Comment: [link](http://cas.ee.ic.ac.uk/people/dt10/research/thomas-10-lut_sr_rngs.pdf)<br/> the block diagram is on page 3 fig1.(A)<br/>When I tried to simulate,the result was "fatal error while loading design"

Comment: That's the only thing it says? The parser doesn't give any more information anywhere about what the problem is?

Comment: module rng (d);
  inout [3:0]d;
 wire [3:0] a;
 //reg a,b,c,d;
  
 
  xorper r(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3]);
  
 dff f1(d[0],clk,a[0],rst);
 dff f2(d[1],clk,a[1],rst);
 dff f3(d[2],clk,a[2],rst);
 dff f4(d[3],clk,a[3],rst);
 
  
  //dff f(d,clk,q,rst);
  //always @(posedge clk) 
  //begin 
 // a=d[0];
 // b=d[1];
 // c=d[2];
 // d=d[3];
//end 
 
endmodule
  Tim......in the first program I didn't assign "a" variable....This program   compiles as well as simulates but I get a blue line for d values.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest starting with an [LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) for random number generation. They are a straight forward shift register, with taps back to a mutlibit XOR to create the feedback bit.

Your implementation of a flop could be better.
1) Add negedge rst to the sensitivity list
2) You do not want to assign x's
3) use non-blocking assignments (<=)

```
reg [3:0] b;

//LFSR feedback bit
wire feedback
assign feedback = b[0] ^ b[3];

// Add active low reset to sensitivity list
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
 if (rst==1'b0) begin
  b[3:0]<=4'hF;  //reset condition first
 end 
 else begin
  b[0]<=feedback;
  b[1]<=b[0];
  b[2]<=b[1];
  b[3]<=b[2];
  //Alternative Verilog might be
  // b = {b[2:0], feedback};
 end
```

For choosing tap point for an LFSR search for a [maximal length LFSR](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/lfsr/index.html). A maximal LFSR will have the longest number sequence before it repeats for a given length of register and tap points.