# verilog Linear feedback shift register random

Tags: random, verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

```
module do2(rst,clk,cout);
input rst,clk;
output [7:0]cout;
reg [2:0]D;
reg [19:0]count;


assign cout=out(D);
always@(posedge clk) begin
count = count+20'd1;
if(rst) begin
D<=3'b0;

end
else if(count==20'd100000)begin

D[0] <=D[1];
D[1] <=D[2];
D[2] <= D[0] ^D[2];
end
end

function [7:0]out;
input [2:0]in;


begin
case(in)
3'b000 : out =8'b11111100 ;
3'b001 : out =8'b01100000 ;
3'b010: out =8'b11011010 ;
3'b011 : out =8'b11110010 ;
3'b100 : out =8'b01100110 ;
3'b101 : out =8'b10110110 ;
3'b110 : out =8'b00111110 ;
3'b111 : out =8'b11100100 ;

endcase 
end

endfunction 
endmodule
```

[image: Snapshot]

I write the verilog programming code using QuartusII.
I want to make a random number generation operation.
Linear Feedback Shift Register is used to generate random number.
But, I don't know why the random pattern is same.
The result of operation like this 8 5 4 2 7 .... 8 5 4 2 7.
How to solve these problem?
Please refer your opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632734/verilog-random-number-generator/12635496#12635496 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800189/why-are-the-outputs-of-this-pseudo-random-number-generator-lfsr-so-predictable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of mistakes in the design:

You have not **initialized** `count` variable here. Along with initializing `D`, `count` must be initialized. After `count` reaches `20'd100000`, it must be **reset or re-initialized**. For next round of randomization.

In the `always` block, the condition `if(rst)` and `else if(count..)` can result into **unintentional hardware**. Adding `else` condition can remove in **unwanted latch creation**.

Also, initially, `D<=3'b0` will have **zero initial seed**, and xoring operation shall also result in **zero output** (`D[0]^D[2] = 0^0 = 0`), so the output shall *never* change. I would prefer to use a `parameter seed = 3'b000` which can easily be **overridden** while instantiation. Like folows:

```
parameter seed = 3'b000 // Arbitrary seed value
if(rst) begin
D<= seed;
count<=20'd0;
end

// While instantiation
do2 #(5) dd(rst,clk,cout);
```

I have provided a testbench at [EDAPlayground here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/QHV), with the above mentioned changes. Kindly go through it.

**EDIT:**

From the comment below, since there are **three bits** for flip flops,  a maximum of **eight** states are possible, hence **output** can contain **maximum of eight states** (as `e4 f2 da b6 60 66 3e`). **Increasing the number of flipflops**, and **conditions in case statements** shall result in **wide range** of output values.

Refer to [Pseudo Random Number Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497877/how-to-implement-a-pseudo-hardware-random-number-generator) link for more robust LFSRs.

Comment: @e19293001 Oh I forgot to mention the main point. Thanks for the inputs, This is due to only three flops (maximum of 8 states) and 8-bit `cout`. This problem is resulting due to lesser number of flop states. I have edited my answer above. Thanks again.